# probability of 2 consecutive events after 3 events

Tags: probability

A box consists of 15 components, 7 of which are defective.

Components are selected and tested, one at a time without replacement, until two consecutive non defective components are obtained. Let X be the number of tests required. Find P(X = 5).

I'm not sure how to go about the consecutive events here. I'm wondering if someone could help me out

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: Are you doing this without replacement?  The probability that the first one chosen is defective is $7/15$.  Then the probability that second one is also defective is $6/14$.

Comment: Hi @saulspatz! Thank you for replying so quickly and helping me out. I deleted my part (a) because I realized it was much simpler than how I went about it. Also as I'm thinking about it, I'm realizing the answer for this 2 consecutive non defective components question would just be adding the probabilities of the different possible outcomes. In the case of N being not defective and D being defective, the different outcomes would be (NDDNN), (DNDNN, and (DDDNN).